# Metasploit exploits "No nop generators succeeded"

Tags: ruby, exploit, metasploit

When running a few Metasploit exploits, after setting all options properly and issue "exploit" command, "No nop generators succeeded" error occurs.

When I try to create payload by myself using msfpayload, this error does not occur, and I am curious why this is occurring.

(One such exploit is squirrelmail_pgp_plugin)

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

That exploit is only suitable for a payload type (CMD) that does not even require NOP-s. It works when you add 'DisableNops'=>true setting into the Payload => {} structure (you have to edit the ruby module file and reload it).
Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/msf/core/exceptions.rb) (which generally is a dreadful experience due to the C/Perl coding conventions applied to Ruby), you'll see an explanation for when this exception gets raised:

> This exception is raised when no NOP generators succeed at generating a sled.

Which payload are you trying you use with this exploit? Or does the error occur with all of the standard payloads? Does the exploit succeed with your custom payload?